# Why are Garmin provided maps inaccurate?

Tags: gps, garmin

Collected tracks on my Garmin GPS (Oregon 450) or in BaseCamp seem to be not in the correct position. There's only a little detail with major highways but it looks as though the route is shifted south, or the highway is shifted north. When viewing the route in Google Earth or Strava, the route follows the road almost perfectly.

Are the Garmin provided maps just really inaccurate or is there something else going on?

Here's a couple pictures so you can see what's going on.  In the Strava image, I'm travelling east-west when I'm north of the highway (which is correct), but on BaseCamp, it shows me travelling east-west when I'm south of the highway.  This has happened with all the tracks I've recorded so far on this route.

[image: Strava image]

[image: BaseCamp image]

Comment: I appears you are in Kanata (aka Ottawa) Ontario...this is a well known area for gps anomolies :)  Dan from Carp

Comment: My first thought was that maybe the highway was moved at some point, but looking at the map it seems very unlikely that the 417 (or even the old 17) ever went along that path.

Comment: It actually looks like it is going down the Carp Road to Hazeldean road then over to old highway 7 towards the golf course

Comment: @DanPatterson It may just be a really old map. It still shows the old highway 16 (now called Prince of Wales Drive), and leaves out the 416. Reading up on highway 417, it may have actually followed that path at one point.  I have no idea why they would be using such old maps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Garmin World base map is very abstracted, so I would not give much on accuracy of that map.

You can try a free Openstreetmap built map for Garmin units of your region, and see if the offset remains. You don't have to put it on the unit itself, they work with Basecamp as well.